Regex redirection from rewrite PHP
in my WordPress backend I have this PHP file listing different post types. Every one has a rewrite rule - I want to change these rules and have the same slug for these posts which has to be '/news-and-insights/%postname%'
I also need to redirect all the existing post (blogs, news, events, press, and insights) from the old slug to the new one. I need a rule for this as there are too many post to redirect them manually.
If possible using an external plugin, I have Yoast Redirection, Redirection, and 301Redirects already in use.
<?php
// Post type 'blog'
add_action('init', 'create_blog_post_type', 4);
function create_blog_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => __('Blog'),
        'singular_name' => __('Blog'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Create New'),
        'edit' => __('Edit'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit'),
        'new_item' => __('New'),
        'view' => __('View'),
        'view_item' => __('View'),
        'search_items' => __('Search'),
        'not_found' => __('Not found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in trash'),
        'parent' => __('Parent'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => __('This is where you can create a new Item.'),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-wordpress',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        '_builtin' => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'blogs/%category%', 'with_front' => true),
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'category'),
    );

    register_post_type('blog', $args);
}


// Post type 'news'
add_action( 'init', 'create_news_post_type', 4 );
function create_news_post_type()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'News' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'News' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Create New' ),
        'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New' ),
        'view' => __( 'View' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Not found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nothing found in trash' ),
        'parent' => __( 'Parent' ),
      );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => __( 'This is where you can create a new Item.' ),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-welcome-widgets-menus',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        '_builtin' => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
        'rewrite' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'news', 'with_front' => true ),
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'category'),
      );

    register_post_type('news',$args);
}

// Post type 'event'
add_action( 'init', 'create_event_post_type', 4 );
function create_event_post_type()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Event' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Event' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Create New' ),
        'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New' ),
        'view' => __( 'View' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Not found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nothing found in trash' ),
        'parent' => __( 'Parent' ),
      );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => __( 'This is where you can create a new Item.' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-calendar',
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        '_builtin' => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
        'rewrite' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'event', 'with_front' => true ),
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'category'),
      );

    register_post_type('event',$args);
}

// Post type 'insights'
add_action( 'init', 'create_insights_post_type', 4 );
function create_insights_post_type()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Insights' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Insights' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Create New' ),
        'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New' ),
        'view' => __( 'View' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Not found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nothing found in trash' ),
        'parent' => __( 'Parent' ),
      );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => __( 'This is where you can create a new Item.' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-book',
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        '_builtin' => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
        'rewrite' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'insights', 'with_front' => true ),
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt' ),
        'taxonomies' => array('insights_type','post_tag', 'category'),
      );

    register_post_type('insights',$args);
}

// Post type 'press'
add_action( 'init', 'create_press_post_type', 4 );
function create_press_post_type()
{
    $labels = array(
        'name' => __( 'Press' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Press' ),
        'add_new' => __( 'Add New' ),
        'add_new_item' => __( 'Create New' ),
        'edit' => __( 'Edit' ),
        'edit_item' => __( 'Edit' ),
        'new_item' => __( 'New' ),
        'view' => __( 'View' ),
        'view_item' => __( 'View' ),
        'search_items' => __( 'Search' ),
        'not_found' => __( 'Not found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'Nothing found in trash' ),
        'parent' => __( 'Parent' ),
      );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => __( 'This is where you can create a new Item.' ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-format-aside',
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        '_builtin' => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
        'rewrite' => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'press', 'with_front' => true ),
        'query_var' => true,
    'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'category'),
        'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'category' ),
      );

    register_post_type('press',$args);
}
?>

I tried modifying the code for the post type blog and add redirection. It works fine for blogs but if I apply the same rule to all these post type, then all the posts crash giving error for too many redirection.
Also note that I can't change the permalink (WordPress Settings) of all the post as there are other post type that can't change their existing slug. I need to write a specific rule for these 5 post type.
<?php
// Post type 'blog'
add_action('init', 'create_blog_post_type', 4);
function create_blog_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => __('Blog'),
        'singular_name' => __('Blog'),
        'add_new' => __('Add New'),
        'add_new_item' => __('Create New'),
        'edit' => __('Edit'),
        'edit_item' => __('Edit'),
        'new_item' => __('New'),
        'view' => __('View'),
        'view_item' => __('View'),
        'search_items' => __('Search'),
        'not_found' => __('Not found'),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __('Nothing found in trash'),
        'parent' => __('Parent'),
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels' => $labels,
        'description' => __('This is where you can create a new Item.'),
        'public' => true,
        'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-wordpress',
        'show_ui' => true,
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'menu_position' => 4,
        'hierarchical' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        '_builtin' => false, // It's a custom post type, not built in!
        'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'news-and-insights', 'with_front' => true),
        'query_var' => true,
        'supports' => array('title', 'editor', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt'),
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag', 'category'),
    );

    register_post_type('blog', $args);
}


// Redirection from old slug to new slug
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_old_blog_urls');
function redirect_old_blog_urls() {
    if (is_singular('blog')) {
        global $post;

        // Check if we're already handling a redirect to avoid an infinite loop
        if (get_query_var('redirected')) {
            return;
        }

        // Get the current URL
        $current_url = home_url(add_query_arg(array(), $wp->request));

        // Define the old URL pattern
        $old_url_pattern = home_url('blogs/' . get_the_category($post->ID)[0]->slug . '/' . $post->post_name);

        // Define the new URL pattern
        $new_url = home_url('news-and-insights/' . $post->post_name);

        // Check if the current URL matches the old URL pattern
        if (untrailingslashit($current_url) === untrailingslashit($old_url_pattern)) {
            // Add a query variable to mark that the redirect has happened
            $new_url = add_query_arg('redirected', '1', $new_url);
            wp_redirect($new_url, 301);
            exit;
        }
    }
}

// Add the query variable to the list of recognized query vars
function add_redirected_query_var($vars) {
    $vars[] = 'redirected';
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_redirected_query_var');

?>

